# Django different url going to the same page

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create 2 extra pages on my Django site, I created the first one with no problem (calendar.html) but when I try to create the second one (actionplan.html) it gives me no error, but when I access xxx/actionplan.html , it shows the calendar.html page... I cannot access xxx/actionplan.html

This is my urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf.urls.static import static


from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView

    urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('', include('blog.urls')),
        url(r'xxx', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="calendar.html")),
        url(r'^xxx/$', DetailView.as_view(template_name="actionplan.html")),
        url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
        url(r'^', include('blog.urls'), name="Blog"),
        ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

This is my views.py:

```
from django.views import generic
from .models import Post

class PostList(generic.ListView):
    queryset = Post.objects.filter(status=1).order_by('-created_on')
    template_name = 'index.html'

class PostDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_detail.html'

class Calendar(generic.DetailView):
   model = Post
   template_name = 'calendar.html'

class Planoacao(generic.DetailView):
   model = Post
   template_name = 'actionplan.html'
```

I have tried:

```
 url(r'^xxx/$', DetailView.as_view(template_name="actionplan.html")),
    url(r'^xxx', DetailView.as_view(template_name="actionplan.html")),
    url(r'^xxx$', DetailView.as_view(template_name="actionplan.html")),
    url(r'xxx', DetailView.as_view(template_name="actionplan.html")),
```

I am officially out of ideas now... can anyone spot a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, in your `urlpatterns` you put the same url two times:

```py
url(r'xxx', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="calendar.html")),
url(r'^xxx/$', DetailView.as_view(template_name="actionplan.html")),
```

You should add a different url for the two views,

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^xxx/plan$', DetailView.as_view(template_name="actionplan.html")),
    url(r'xxx', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="calendar.html")),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('blog.urls'), name="Blog"),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and you should use `path` no url and not both

Comment: try again, it should be by url, it expect a regex them xxx match with the url, try putting calendar url first

Answer (score 2):

You've given them the same url essentially, `yoursite.com/xxx`,  you could reorder them and put the one with the slash first and that *might* work but then that would make it a nightmare if you use django's `APPEND_SLASH` setting.

To fix, make your urls unique

The `actionplan.html` has nothing to do with your url, its "working" only because the regex for the calendar is just looking for `xxx` in the given url